# replace text with a variable

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I want to replace the value with a variable. The following does not work because of the single quote used in sed.

```
#!/bin/sh
set myvarM='pqr'
sed 's/:P03:M15/:P02:M1$myvarM/' mychange.txt > new_mychange.txt
```

Can I change the sed command or should I use something else?

Comment: use `"` instead, will allow variables to be expanded

Comment: Thanks and the second problem was with set !

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
myvarM='pqr'
sed "s/:P03:M15/:P02:M1$myvarM/" mychange.txt > new_mychange.txt
```

Incidentally, to make the replacement in-place (ie not create a new file, but alter the original file), do this:

```
sed -i '' "s/:P03:M15/:P02:M1$myvarM/" mychange.txt
```

This says "use a blank as the increment suffix" - ie write out the same filename as the input

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v val="$myvarM" '{sub(/:P03:M15/, ":P02:M1" val); print}' filename
```

Note that in a bourne-type shell ("/bin/sh") the `set` command sets the positional parameters. Your first line sets `$1` to the value `myvarM='pqr'` -- the myvarM variable continues to be unset.